# karate | xml post method exeuction

Tags: karate

I’m having issue with xml post request where post method is not executed. When I try to post same request body in post man it worked.My test is success with 200 but actual request is not executed.
Please let me know if I’m missing

To pass the request body,I’m calling through java object and payload is correctly constructed and printed.In execution test is success and doesn’t print response.But actually test is not executed.
Only headers are printed.

***************** create-user.feature*****************

Feature: create ims user for provided country
  Requires country code,

Background:

```
# load secrets from json
* def createuser = Java.type('com.user.JavaTestData')
* def create = createuser.createUser("US")
```

Scenario: get service token

Given url imscreateuserurl
And request create
When method post
Then status 200
* print response
***************** create-user.feature*****************

---

Here is java class

```
public class JavaTestData {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JavaTestData.class);

     public static String createUser(String countryCodeInput) {
        logger.debug("create user for country code input", countryCodeInput);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Peter, here is my feature file
Feature: create ims user for provided country
  Requires country code, 
  Background:
    # load secrets from json
    * def createuser = Java.type('com.adobe.imscreateuser.JavaTestData')
    * def create = createuser.createUser("US")

Scenario: get service token

Given url imscreateuserurl
 And header Content-Type = 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'
 And request create
 When method post
 Then status 200
* print response

I have performed print for create and showing complete payload.At when method post -> statement its going as null or empty...

Not sure where it is missing

Comment: I am not sure either :) also I edited my original answer, please check. adding answers like this is not proper etiquette on stack overflow.

Comment: one thing if i pass xml to def varaiable and post method is working as expected. Only difference reading java class and passing to request is NOT working

Comment: must be some simple mistake you are making

Answer (score 0):

Unless you post a [full working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), no one can help you. Pretty clear that the value of `create` is null or empty.

Also I personally think you are wasting your time using Java. The whole point of Karate is to avoid using Java as far as possible.

Look at these examples for ideas: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature

Edit: also refer to the doc on type-conversion: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion